# video.js not able to rewind on live stream

Tags: video.js

I have a HLS stream which is determined as live as it has no #EXT-X-ENDLIST however I am writing the whole file to disk as a recording.

When this opens in video.js it detects it as live and removes the seek bar.

I want to be able to set the start position and seek backwards or forwards in the stream.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you modify the manifest at any point to have an EXT-X-ENDLIST? If it's live it should continue to refresh the manifest.

Otherwise you can set the duration manually if it has no duration or duration is Infinity.

```
myPlayer.duration(60);
```

And remove the live CSS class manually

```
myPlayer.removeClass('vjs-live');
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me as still just showed up as live, what am I doing wrong? https://gist.github.com/sinkers/73312c474a8e7ece5998   I did consider adding the EXT-X-ENDLIST it is actually a live stream. It does work with this player though: http://osmfhls.kutu.ru/

Comment: This solution: myPlayer.duration(60); works, but only for a short period(~3s), because the player keeps adding vjs-live classe periodically, Any solution?